# Read image file from SD card on emulator

Tags: java, android

finally I managed to move some image file to the SD-card on the Android emulator. I have a task to create a application that use a grid layout to show small images, and I guess I should load the thumbnail images from the SD-card and not have the images in the res/drawable-ldpi folder in the project folder and load them from there?! I have also anmount/mount the SD-card on the emulator.

I have a lot of work to do to create this application. Is there a simple way to load on or all the images from the SD-card, just to see if it's working? Thanks!